# Extract T from class<T> and use T in class building

Tags: haxe

I want to take a `Class<T>` that i've gotten from `Type.resolveClass()` and use it to build a variable of type T in a class. I'm not quite sure how to describe it so here's some code that hopefully describes it well enough.

```
public static function build(name:String) { 
var fields = Context.getBuildFields();
// Get Class<T>
var resolved = Type.resolveClass(name); 

// Do some magic to get a ComplexType that represents the T in Class<T>
var type = magic(resolved); // I want to find out how to do this

// Create a field of type T
fields.push({
  name: "ofTypeName",
  pos: Context.currentPos(),
  access: [AStatic, APublic],
  kind: FVar(type, macro null)
});


return fields;
}
```

So I want to know how to get a `ComplexType` out of `Class<T>` which represents `T`

Comment: `Type.resolveClass()` (runtime reflection) seems quite out of place in a macro. There's a good chance that the class in question wasn't even loaded in macro context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var type = Context.getType(name);
var ctype = TypeTools.toComplexType(type);
```